# Android Spinner SetSelection getCount()

Tags: android, spinner

I want my spinner to setselection() from a string which retrieved from php mysql.

```
private class RetrievePersonal extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(VirtualIC.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading personal details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        int success;
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("accountID", accountID));

            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_personal_details, "GET", params);

            Log.d("Personal Details>>", json.toString());

            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                JSONArray personalObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PERSONAL);

                JSONObject prsl = personalObj.getJSONObject(0);

                FindViewById();

                name = prsl.getString("name");
                nric = prsl.getString("nric");
                nationality = prsl.getString("nationality");
                religion = prsl.getString("religion");
                races = prsl.getString("races");
                gender = prsl.getString("nationality");
                dob = prsl.getString("dob");
                email = prsl.getString("email");
                mobile = prsl.getString("mobileNum");
                home = prsl.getString("homeNum");
                address = prsl.getString("address");
                postcode = prsl.getString("postcode");
                city = prsl.getString("city");
                state = prsl.getString("state");
                country = prsl.getString("country");
            }else{
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.toString();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();

        FindViewById();

        inputName.setText(name);
        inputNric.setText(nric);
        inputNationality.setText(nationality);
        inputReligion.setText(nationality);
        inputRaces.setText(nationality);

        if(gender.equals("M")){
            inputGender.setSelection(getIndex(inputGender, "Male"));
        }else{
            inputGender.setSelection(getIndex(inputGender, "Female"));
        }

        inputDay.setSelection(getIndex(inputDay, day));
        inputMonth.setSelection(getIndex(inputMonth, month));
        inputYear.setSelection(getIndex(inputYear, year));

        inputEmail.setText(email);
        inputMobileNum.setText(mobile);
        inputHomeNum.setText(home);
        inputAddress.setText(address);
        inputPostcode.setText(postcode);
        inputCity.setText(city);

        inputState.setSelection(getIndex(inputDay, state));

        if(getIndex(inputCountry, country) > 0) {
            inputCountry.setSelection(getIndex(inputCountry, country));
        }else{
            inputCountry.setSelection(getIndex(inputCountry, "Others"));
            countryOtherLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            inputCountryOther.setText(country);
        }
    }
}
```

getIndex() which return the position...

```
private int getIndex(Spinner spinner, String string){
    int index = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<spinner.getCount();i++){
        if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(string)) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }else{
            index = -1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

this is what i get.....

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.Spinner.getCount()' on a null object reference

Please help? Thank you.

```
private void FindViewById(){
    inputGender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.gender);
    inputMonth = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.month);
    inputState = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.state);

    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    inputNric = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nric);
    inputNationality = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nationality);
    inputReligion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.religion);
    inputRaces = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.races);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputMobileNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contactnum_hp);
    inputHomeNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contactnum_home);
    inputAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
    inputPostcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.postcode);
    inputCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.city);
    inputCountryOther = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.countryOther);

    countryLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.countryLayout);

    nameLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.nameLayout);
    nricLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.nricLayout);
    nationalityLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.nationalityLayout);
    religionLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.religionLayout);
    racesLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.racesLayout);
    emailLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.emailLayout);
    hpLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.contactHPLayout);
    homeLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.contactHomeLayout);
    addressLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.addressLayout);
    postcodeLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.postcodeLayout);
    cityLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.cityLayout);
    countryOtherLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.countryOtherLayout);
}
```

Comment: check your spinner is null. or post complete code

Comment: how to check the spinner is null?

if(spinner != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < spinner.getCount(); i++) {
                if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(string)) {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                } else {
                    index = -1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }else{
            Log.d("spinner is null", String.valueOf(index));
        }


is it like this?

Comment: what did you in FindViewById(); add complete code

Comment: FindViewById() is mainly to retrieve element from UI

Comment: where  did you add adapter to spinner ?

Comment: in OnCreate().. i got used adapter to spinner and string array to populate spinner...but now i retrieve the value from php mysql as string....when i want to set selection to spinner..it cant..

Comment: did you call FindViewById( ) before adding adapter

Comment: i solved it~ thank you~